# How is full duplex transmission possible in OMAP4460 UART?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, uart

The base address for THR and RHR registers are same. So is it possible to transmit and receive at the same time?

Comment: This is specific you particular hardware - you have not specified.

Comment: I don't understand why there is a down vote for this question ?.Can you please describe it.So that i can avoid in the future

Comment: Probably because it is regarded as off-topic, being primarily hardware related rather than about code. In which case it should be voted for close which it has not. If someone objects to a question, it is good manners to post an explanatory comment, or just fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

It is specific to your particular UART hardware implementation, but it is unlikely that they are in fact the same register.  They are two registers that have the same address - one is read-only (RHR), the other write-only (THR), so they do not need separate addresses.

In the hardware logic the correct register will be selected depending on the state of the read/write logic state as if that were an additional address line.

So yes, full duplex operation will be supported.  You should read the user manual and/or data sheet for your particular part.